# Facebook Open Graph Scraping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've recently enabled the Facebook Open Graph stuff on my web app (so and so has just read this and that on here and there). Now I post the request to Facebook when a user posts something, as part of the page load in the controller. The problem is I receive the following error:

> HTTP 500: Response body: {"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"Could
>   not retrieve data from URL."}}

My first thought is that the open request to load the page is blocking any FB scraping of OG information, as it seems after it's been cached I no longer receive this error.

Is this likely? If so, what's the best way to work around it?

Comment: There are a number of different problems that can occur, so it may help to post the URL you are testing with. Also, you can force a rescrape using the [Facebook Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). That may give you some information regarding errors, and at least you can monitor your access logs for a request from `facebookexternalhit` to verify whether or not your object is being cached.

Answer (score 3):

WHY THIS HAPPENS: 
I had this same problem today, and it is because your Koala script (assuming you're using koala - if not, you should try it out because it's great) sends its request to Facebook before your URL is up. This means that when Facebook registers the post, it comes to the URL you specified to pick up the meta tags. Unfortunately, the page itself hasn't been loaded yet, giving it a 500 error

HOW TO SOLVE IT: 
Use the [delayed_job gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/delayed_job) to prevent your post call from occurring before the page loads, which allows facebook to scrape your metatags correctly.

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
def post_to_facebook([ACCESS_TOKEN])
  graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new([ACCESS TOKEN])
  graph.put_connections("me", "[APP NAMESPACE]:[ACTION]", :[OBJECT TYPE] => [OBJECT_URL])
end
handle_asynchronously :post_to_facebook
```